# How to keep track of default function arguments?

Tags: python, optional-parameters

I have a bunch of function what call each other which have a few optional parameters:

```
def f0(..., p1=3, p2=5):
    ...
def f1(..., p1=3, p2=5, p3=8, p4=13):
    ...
    f0(..., p1=p1, p2=p2)
    ...
def f2(..., p1=3, p2=5, p3=8, p4=13, p5=21, p6=123):
    ...
    f1(..., p1=p1, p2=p2, p3=p3, p4=p4)
    ...
def f3(..., p1=3, p2=5, p3=8, p4=13, p5=21, p6=123, ...):
    ...
    f2(..., p1=p1, p2=p2, p3=p3, p4=p4, p5=p5, p6=p6)
    ...
```

Obviously, I don't want to keep repeating those default values (123, 21, 13 &c)
all the time. It would also be nice to be able to pass `None` *explicitly* to
mean "use the appropriate default".

The obvious way to deal with this is something like

```
p1_default=3
p2_default=5
def f0(..., p1=None, p2=None):
    p1 = p1 if p1 is not None else p1_default
    p2 = p2 if p2 is not None else p2_default
    ...
p3_default=12
p4_default=15
def f1(..., p1=None, p2=None, p3=None, p4=None):
    p3 = p3 if p3 is not None else p3_default
    p4 = p4 if p4 is not None else p4_default
    ...
    f0(..., p1=p1, p2=p2)
    ...
```

but this looks ugly and repetitive.

What is the "pythonic" way?

Comment: But, surely in your first snippet your line `f0(..., p1=p1, p2=p2)` can just be: `f0(...)` because of the defaults.

Comment: In what way is this repetitive, other than you are doing the same *kind* of thing multiple times (but each one is distinct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommended using keyword arguments instead of positional arguments.

```
def f0(..., *, p1=3, p2=5):
    ...

def f1(..., *, p3=8, p4=13, **kwargs):
    ...
    f0(..., **kwargs)
    ...

def f2(..., *, p5=21, p6=123, **kwargs):
    ...
    f1(..., **kwargs)
    ...

def f3(..., **kwargs):
    ...
    f2(..., **kwargs)
```

When you need to supply non-default values, you need to do a small amount of extra typing, but given the number of parameters you seem to have, this will probably be simpler than trying to remember the order in which argunents need to be provided. For example:

```
# p2 is still 5, p3 is still 8, p6 is still 123, etc
f3(p1=7, p5=16, p4=12)
```

Note, too, that `16` is assigned directly to `p5` in the call to `f2`, rather than being collected in *its* `kwargs`, so it won't be passed down to `f1`.

Comment: Forgot about `**kwargs`!!! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try kwargs, parameters passed in like a dictionary.

```
def f0(**kwargs):
    p1 = kwargs.get('p1', 3)
    p2 = kwargs.get('p2', 5)
    print(f"f0: p1={p1}, p2={p2}")

def f1(**kwargs):
    p3 = kwargs.get('p3', 8)
    p4 = kwargs.get('p4', 13)
    f0(**kwargs)
    print(f"f1: p3={p3}, p4={p4}")
```

It can be called as usual:

```
f1(p1=3, p2=88)
```

And will also have a default value when the argument is not passed:

```
f1()
```

**Suggestions**

However, I do not like purely using kwargs because there will be no hinting of parameter names. Furthermore, if you pass in the wrong parameter name you will not be warned, and the function will treat it as "no arguments passed in".

Example `p1` is wrongly typed as `o1`, ending up in `f1(o1=4)`, which will behave the same as `f1()`

My personal solution is creating a `class` that contains the parameters:

```
class DK:  # Default Keys
    p1 = 'p1'
    p2 = 'p2'
```

then pass it into the function like this to avoid any silly mistakes:

```
f1(DK.p1 = 4, DK.p2 = 99)
```

**Extra**

If you find using `.get()` being repetitive, you can use kwargs directly to get the values.

First, create a global `dict` that stores the default values

```
default_params = {
    'p1': 3,
    'p2': 5,
    'p3': 8,
    'p4': 13,
}
```

then do:

```
def f0(**kwargs):
    kwargs = {key:kwargs.get(key, val) for key, val in default_params.items()}
    print(f"f0: p1={kwargs['p1']}, p2={kwargs['p2']}")

def f1(**kwargs):
    kwargs = {key:kwargs.get(key, val) for key, val in default_params.items()}
    f0(**kwargs)
    print(f"f1: p3={kwargs['p3']}, p4={kwargs['p4']}")
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a bunch of function what call each other

Seems you have bad architecture. Guess the problem is in repeated functions but repeated parameters.

Hence I suppose writing one recursive function:

```py
def f(..., **kwargs):
    # optionally validate kwargs names
    if len(kwargs)>2:
        # process external kwargs
        f(..., **dict(list(kwargs.items())[:-2]))
    else:
        # process baseline kwargs
```

Here:

- `**kwargs` packs keyword arguments into `dict`.
- `**dict(list(kwargs.items())[:-2])` removes two last elements from kwargs and unpacks rest to `f` recursive call arguments.